# SVG not loading up in live server

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a website and got to the SVG part and it just won't show up. I can drag it to the top of the tab and it shows up there but not on the live server website. Here is the HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GR Official Site</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__container">
            <a href="/" id="navbar__logo">GR</a>
            <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="navbar__menu">
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="/" class="navbar__links">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="/warships.html" class="navbar__links">Warships [IN DEVELOPMENT]</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="/shop.html" class="navbar__links">Shop</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="/News.html" class="navbar__links">News</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar__btn">
                    <a href="/" class="button">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main Section -->
    <div class="main">
        <div class="main__container">
            <div class="main__content">
                <h1>Warships</h1>
                <p>The worlds next battle royale game.</p>
                <button class="main__btn"><a href="/warships.html">Learn More</a></a></button>
            </div>
            <div class="ws__img0--containter">
                <img src="assets/images/GRLC.svg" alt="pic1" id="main__img">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    background: #0024c7;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

#navbar__logo {
    background-color: #28caf3;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #28caf3, #93e5f3, #ffffff);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.3rem;
}

.fa-gem {
    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar__item {
    height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar__btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #08657c;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.button:hover {
    background: #1216ff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
    color: #28caf3;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
    .navbar__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar__menu {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        height: 50vh;
        z-index: -1;
        background: #0024c7;
    }

    .navbar__menu.active {
        background: #0024c7;
        top: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 50vh;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }

    #navbar__logo {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background: #ffffff;
    }

    .navbar__item {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar__links {
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    #mobile-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
    }

    .navbar__btn {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0%;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
}


/* Main Section.Styles */
.main {
    background-color: #415dd6;
}

.main__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: #415dd6;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0 50px;

}

.main__container h2 {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #cccccc, #eeeeee, #ffffff);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #cccccc, #eeeeee, #ffffff);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #f4f4f8;
}

.main__btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0453ff, #049bff);
    padding: 14px 32px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #006eff;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    outline: none;
}

.main__btn a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #cccccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main__btn:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #0453ff;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.main__btn:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.main__btn:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

.ws__img0--container {
    text-align: center;
}

#mobile__img {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Someone, please help me I know this is a lot of code but idc how long you take. I just need help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: By the way, it actually worked with another SVG it just doesn't work with this one I made in PhotoShop or PS.

Comment: Check browser console for errors. Specifically 404 and "incorrect mime type" errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by turning the SVG into a PNG. I got this idea from a sensei at code ninjas.

Comment: but svg is vectorized, png is an image. This doesn't solve the issue if you want to keep it vectorized

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your page is not valid?

```
Error: The element a must not appear as a descendant of the button element.    
From line 47, column 43; to line 47, column 67    
ain__btn"><a href="/warships.html">Learn 

Error: Stray end tag a.    
From line 47, column 82; to line 47, column 85    
n More</a></a></butt
```

Comment: Yannick that did not work. That is what the learn more button does.